# How to create multilayer neural network in browser using database data for prediction

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, encog

I am trying to create multilayer neural network in browser. I looked for many java library for doing this. Finally I'm trying with encog. I tested the encog examples from github. Now I need to do same with database datas. And also I need to plot neural network. Could anyone help me for this. I searched alot and came across with Neuroph studio, synaptic js, encog. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Done the encog XORSQL example too. But it doesnot satisfy my requirements.

Comment: cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/